# New certificate not being recognized in iis10

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-10

I inherited maintaining a 2012 server.  The certificate for our websites expired, so i installed a new one.  It is still as if it is using the old one.  We have many websites all on different ports.  If I go to the bindings, they all have the new cert selected and it does not expire until 2020.  When i click browse on the website and browse with local host, it shows expired.  The same from the outside if I go to https://www.digicert.com/help/ and put in the url.  One of the subdomains actually works and shows the new certificate.  If I do netsh http show sslcert > c:\temp\certlog.txt it shows the new cert for each binding.  Is it possible that the cert is being handled by a proxy or something?  How could I tell?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Have worked on this for a week without getting to the bottom of it.  Also, our main website (www.) is not on the same server as the subdomain websites that are not working.  We have a wildcard cert.

```
  IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:7813
    Certificate Hash             : 35091bc455e3534fc0f513adf619478971e20fe5
    Application ID               : {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
    Certificate Store Name       : My
    Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Enabled
    Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
    Usage Check                  : Enabled
    Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
    URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
    Ctl Identifier               : (null)
    Ctl Store Name               : (null)
    DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
    Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
    Reject Connections           : Disabled
    Disable HTTP2                : Not Set
```

Comment: I assume since this has been going on for a week you have already tried restarting the IIS service, and the server?

Comment: Yes, restarted both.

Comment: Would IIS use a different cert that the showssl cert?

Comment: Not sure what showssl reports to you.  Does this command show the thumbprint of the cert you expect?  `ipmo IISAdministration, WebAdministration ; Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings |select-object *`?

Comment: I found the showssl example and assumed it was showing how the server would respond.  Here is an example:

Comment: Added showssl output to original post.

Comment: I see that is on port 7813?  When you access your site are  you going to `https://fqdn:7813/`?  If not, then you probably have a proxy or something in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was, but we re-installed the certificate and rebooted and made sure the old one was gone and now it is working properly.